# How to sync user directory on bitbucket server to jira with both running on aks?

Tags: kubernetes, jira, bitbucket-server, azure-aks

#### When trying to sync the user directories of Jira to other atlassian products (confluence and bitbucket server running on aks) a 403 error is returned.

Upon looking into this error the following steps have been attempted:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/unable-to-connect-to-jira-for-authentication-forbidden-403-323391874.html

The IP adresses have been added to the whitelist of Jira. The next step in solutions online is to restart the Jira
service.

This however causes issues as upon running the stop/start-jira.sh files inside the pod the service returns 
with none of the previous settings and all configurations including backups are gone. Taking us back to square one.

```
cluster size:

current set-up 
3 x Standard D8 v3 (8 vcpus, 32 GiB memory) cluster on aks

Used the following images installed through UI: 

atlassian/jira-software
cptactionhank/docker-atlassian-jira

Exec into pod and go to /opt/atlassian/jira/bin

run ./(start/stop)-jira.sh
```

What should happen is that when going back to the url the Jira instance is reset and all configuration files in the pod for the service are lost.

The logs of the pod give error no 137 as a common error when restarting.

update:

https://github.com/int128/devops-kompose/tree/master/atlassian-jira-software

The following helm chart has also been used and achieved the same result.

Comment: please share helm charts that you used while deploying them ?

Comment: no helm charts used. Just done using the docker images listed and deployed form the kubernetes dashboard. Ah sorry my colleague has tried the following helm chart
 https://github.com/int128/devops-kompose/tree/master/atlassian-jira-software with the same issue found.